# Import CSV file into database

Tags: php

I'm using following function to import the csv file into db. All is working fine. But I'm also want its also insert `$_SESSION['userid']` with CSV file. please help me. thanks

```
    function csv_file_to_mysql_table($source_file, $target_table, $max_line_length=10000) { 
            if (($handle = fopen("$source_file", "r")) !== FALSE) { 
                $columns = fgetcsv($handle, $max_line_length, ","); 
                foreach ($columns as &$column) { 
                    $column = str_replace(".","",$column); 
                } 
                $insert_query_prefix = "INSERT INTO $target_table (".join(",",$columns).")\nVALUES"; 
                while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, $max_line_length, ",")) !== FALSE) { 
                    while (count($data)<count($columns)) 
                        array_push($data, NULL); 
                    $query = "$insert_query_prefix (".join(",",quote_all_array($data)).");"; 
                    mysql_query($query); 
                } 
                fclose($handle); 
            } 
        } 

        function quote_all_array($values) { 
            foreach ($values as $key=>$value) 
                if (is_array($value)) 
                    $values[$key] = quote_all_array($value); 
                else 
                    $values[$key] = quote_all($value); 
            return $values; 
        } 

        function quote_all($value) { 
            if (is_null($value)) 
                return "NULL"; 

            $value = "'" . mysql_real_escape_string($value) . "'"; 
            return $value; 
        }
        csv_file_to_mysql_table($uploadfile,"import_csv");
        echo "file is imported successfully!";
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I imagine something like this would work. Just append the extra field after you do your array joins.

I don't know what your user_id column is called, i just assumed user_id

```
$insert_query_prefix = "INSERT INTO $target_table (".join(",",$columns).",user_id)\nVALUES";
```

add the user_id value to the values argument

```
$query = "$insert_query_prefix (".join(",",quote_all_array($data)).",".$_SESSION['userid'].");";
```

Comment: getting error message. ` Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_FUNCTION in C:\wamp\www\user_events\upload_csv.php on line 28`. This is line no. 28 `function csv_file_to_mysql_table($source_file, $target_table, $max_line_length=10000) { `

Comment: I don't know what to tell you. I just tested my changes as written in a php syntax checker and everything is fine. If you retyped what it wrote you might want to double check quotes, semi-colons, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Look for "ADD HERE"... just tack the column name in after you get them and also add the data to the end of your array once its built...  should be simple as that.

```
            foreach ($columns as &$column) { 
                $column = str_replace(".","",$column); 
            }
//ADD HERE
$columns[] = "userid";
            $insert_query_prefix = "INSERT INTO $target_table (".join(",",$columns).")\nVALUES"; 
            while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, $max_line_length, ",")) !== FALSE) { 
                while (count($data)<count($columns)) 
                    array_push($data, NULL); 
//ADD HERE
$data[] = $_SESSION['userid']

                $query = "$insert_query_prefix (".join(",",quote_all_array($data)).");"; 
                mysql_query($query);
```